# The wrong url is showing up for my site in google searches

Tags: apache, redirect, seo

Hey folks.  I have a client who's old website was called toastkid.com.  I set up a new site, alekskrotoski.com, and had the old www.toastkid.com domain point to the new site.  I have a 301 redirect working, so when you go to www.toastkid.com the address bar updates to alekskrotoski.com.  So, the 301 is definitely working fine.

However, i also expected that google would update it's search results to say alekskrotoski.com, effectively transferring all the google juice over.  But, it still says www.toastkid.com in a search for 'aleks krotoski'.  I did the redirect on thursday night (3 days ago at time of writing) and thought it would have taken effect by now.  How long would it normally take for google to update its index?  Is there anything i can do to speed it up?  Could there be anything stopping it?  The site is already registered and verified with google webmaster.

Grateful for any advice - max

Comment: Why the name change? `toastkid.com` is a domain name to rule them all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. A few days are not going to cut it, it can take weeks until a change has arrived in the index.

To gain information about how Google sees your page, you can register with [**Google Webmaster Tools**](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=sitemaps&passive=true&nui=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fwebmasters%2Ftools%2F&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fwebmasters%2Ftools%2F&hl=en). *Maybe* if you register both sites, and add a [**Sitemap**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps), you can make Google aware of the transition faster.

Otherwise, just wait. The change is going to take effect eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You must wait at least 1 week to see the update of the URLs in SERP.
Much depends on the trust of your old site that determines the frequency of crawling.

However Google will continue to try periodically (monthly, annually) crawl the old URLs, don't consider this

Answer (score 1):

Would you want all your hard earned Google juice to go elsewhere just because your site was misconfigured for a a few days? I don't think so. You shouldn't want this to change quickly.